# "landscape" leads to page shrinking in Latex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

If you run this, you can see that all pages after `\begin{landscape}` are too small."Page 4" at the bottom for example should be 90% into the page, but it's more like 70%. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\printanswers
\begin{document}
Page1
\newpage
Page2
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{solution}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
     \end{solution}
     \end{landscape}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558017/exam-document-class-and-pdflscape-causing-unwanted-margin-changes